# Hyperlink '?' Escaping

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a hyperlink with a queryparam in the following format:

```
<a href="<%= Url.Content("~/Search/Results/" + 
        ViewData["SearchID"] + "?listingID=" + 
        ViewData.Model.ListingID) %>">
    See more
</a>
```

Shows up fine in the source of the page however when clicked I end up with:

```
http://localhost/{Site}/Search/Results/30%3FlistingID=2
```

I've tried using the ActionLink helper:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("See more", "Results", "Search", 
        new { 
            id = ViewData["SearchID"], 
            listingID = ViewData.Model.ListingID 
        }, null) %>
```

I've even tried registering a route specific to this action:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "SearchResults", // Route name
    "Search/Results/{id}/{listingID}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Search", 
          action = "Results", 
          id = UrlParameter.Optional, 
          listingID = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

I'm really baffled as to why the url shows up fine in the generated page source but not in the actual request url once clicked on. Any input?

**Edit**
The url shows up properly in the generated page's source:

```
<a href="/[SITE]/Search/Results/30?listingID=2">See more</a>
```

Entering the above url manually into the address bar works properly oddly enough. Really baffled.

**Second EDIT**

The real reason that url thing is a problem is that I'm getting an error:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (?).
```

**Final Edit**

I found the cause of the problem. The request was coming from https to http and there is an attribute on the target Controller that rewrites the url to be http. **/FacePalm**

Comment: What happens when you use `Html.ActionLink`? I use it like this in a lot of places and I never had a problem.

Comment: @Ronald: When I use ActionLink I get the same hyperlink path however upon following the link I get the same result w/ "http://localhost/[SITE]/Search/Results/30%3FlistingID=2" showing in the address bar.

Comment: @Casey: What browser do you use? What's the encoding of the generated html file? Can you save the generated file to your desktop, open the html file in your browser and check the link again?

Comment: I'm using IE9. 

I'm not specifying an encoding.

Oddly when I save the page's html, add "http://localhost" to the links, and load the page in the browser the links work properly.

Answer (score 0):

The url is turning your "?" into the uri encoded value: %3F. The reason that this is happening is because the string is being uri encoded. You need to escape the question mark.

Comment: Now it basically says "it's being encoded because it's being encoded" and does not provide a proper solution. :)

Comment: @Tomalak Darn it! Logic and English grammar has foiled me again! - fixed to string is being uri encoded.

Answer (score 0):

UrlHelper.Content is assuming everything is a protocol, host, and path, it really doesn't do query variables.

UriBuilder might help.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to generating the link since it shows up properly in the page's source:
<a href="/[Site]/Search/Results/30?listingID=2">See more</a>

Comment: @Casey: That is not possible.

Comment: @Tomalak: Which part? The page url shows properly in the page's source. I'd love to have something more straightforward wrong but ...

Comment: @Casey: If the page URL were in fact proper in the page source, then obviously it would be proper when you click on the link. Some aspect of your observation must be wrong -- *or* your server is rewriting the URL, but that's an entirely different problem. We don't have enough information to help you here.